# Problems with conditional statement in jQuery

Tags: json, jquery, conditional-statements

I'm having a problem handling some numbers from a json request. Based on the results I'm trying to output some various bits of HTML. Specifically the problem is when I come to check whether a number is greater than -1, but less than 6. Code excerpt is as follows…

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) < -1) {
//this is where one thing happens
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > -1) {
//Something else happens here
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > 6) {
//This is where the third thing should happen, but doesn't?
}
```

It seems that despite the value being 7 or 70 the second 'else if' is as far as it gets.

Is there a way that I can check that the number is more than -1 but less than 6 so that it moves on to the next conditional statement.

I'm guessing that (like my previous question) there's a very simple answer so please excuse my naivety.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions are executed only until *one* is found to be true.

In other words, you need to re-jig their order or tighten them to make your current order work.

7 is above -1, so the second condition resolves to true. So for 7, the 3rd condition is never needed.

```
if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) < -1) {
    //number is less than -1
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > 6) {
    //number is above 6
}
else {
    //neither, so must be inbetween -1 an 6
}
```

Comment: – Thank you! Amazingly quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition is wrong. Let's think of this: myvariable is 7.

In your code will happen:

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) < -1) {
//this is where one thing happens
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > -1) {
**// HERE THE CONDITION IS TRUE, BECAUSE 7 > -1**
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > 6) {
// This is where the third thing should happen, but doesn't?
}
```

You can change it as

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) < -1) {
//this is where one thing happens
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > 6) {
// This is where the third thing should happen, but doesn't?
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > -1) {
 // Moved
}
```

To make it work...

Answer (score 0):

yes because any number you will write greater than -1 will never go throw the third block of code , it will go throw the second, as you said "**the number is more than -1 but less than 6**" you can simply do like this :

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) < -1) {
//this is where one thing happens
}
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > -1 && parseInt(myvariable, 10) < 6) {
//Something else happens here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change the second line:

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) > -1)
```

to:

```
else if(parseInt(myvariable, 10) <= 6)
```

There are so many ways of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this easily do something like this:

considering your variable value is (7):

```
else if(parseInt(myVariable, 10) &lt; -1) {
//this is where one thing happens
}
else if(parseInt(myVariable, 10) > -1) {
//now 'myVariable' is greater than -1, then let's check if it is greater than 6
if(parseInt(myVariable, 10) > 6) {
//this where what you should do if 'myVariable' greater than -1 AND greater than 6
}
}
```